# How to permute row elements from table

Tags: python, list, permutation

I have the following table:

```
table = [['5p,aa', '3p,ggg'], ['pippo,3', 'gigio,777']]
```

I want to generate for each row all combinations for each row, as follows:

```
5p,3p 5p,ggg aa,3p aa,ggg pippo,gigio pippo,777 3,gigio 3,777
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: What does "I have the following table" actually means? In which language? Are those DBMS tables?

Comment: google itertools permutations

Comment: @GoBrewers14: From the desired output, they want `itertools.product`, even though they say permutations.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> table = [['5p,aa', '3p,ggg'], ['pippo,3', 'gigio,777']]
>>> rows = [[cell.split(',') for cell in row] for row in table]
>>> [list(itertools.product(*row)) for row in rows]
[[('5p', '3p'), ('5p', 'ggg'), ('aa', '3p'), ('aa', 'ggg')],
 [('pippo', 'gigio'), ('pippo', '777'), ('3', 'gigio'), ('3', '777')]]
```